# Barcode return bookmarking event

Tags: javascript, barcode, bookmarks

I'm working with my scanning project, currently using a 2d barcode reader. When i try to scan a 2D barcode using usb barcode reader let say put the information on the input box, but after the reader enter the information on the textbox it triggers bookmarking event in the browser.
How to prevent the bookmarking event being trigger by the reader after scanning? Is there any javascript solution to catch the event? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery and this function `event.preventDefault();` of which you can find more here http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Answer (score 0):

```
        window.document.body.onkeydown = function (e) {
            //MSIE
            if (window.event) {
                //only allow ctrl+c,ctrl+f,ctrl+v,ctrl+x,ctrl+z                    
                if ((event.ctrlKey && e.which < 100) && (event.ctrlKey && (e.which != 67 && e.which != 70 && e.which != 86 && e.which != 88 && e.which != 90))) {
                    //alert("The CTRL key + F was pressed!");
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            }
            //firefox && chrome
            else {
                key = e.which;
                //only allow ctrl+c,ctrl+f,ctrl+v,ctrl+x,ctrl+z                    
                if ((e.ctrlKey && e.which < 100) && (e.ctrlKey && (e.which != 67 && e.which != 70 && e.which != 86 && e.which != 88 && e.which != 90))) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        }
```

I thinks this codes can help you.